# Dojo Elements compatible with jstl tags ?

Tags: javascript, forms, dojo, jstl

When i write

```
<form:input id="xyz" dojoType="somedojoelement"/>
```

it gives me error that dojoType not compatible with JSTL. Is it not possible to use dojoelements while inputting some value using JSTL tags.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will be able to do this this way, you will have do some workaround like in this tutorial: [Combine JSF with Dojo widgets](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-jsfdojo/index.html). Is this what are you looking for?